# Unpleasant situations happen?

Tags: phrases, expressions

> Unfortunately sometimes things don't go the way we want. Unpleasant
>   situations happen.

Is the phrase "Unpleasant situations happen" correct?

Maybe instead of happen it would be better to use 'occur'? Or is 'happen' fine?

Comment: I think most NES would take it to be a polite version of "shit happens".

Comment: It would be more idiomatic to say that situations *arise*, not "happen". https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=situations+arise%2Csituations+happen&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csituations%20arise%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csituations%20happen%3B%2Cc0  *We need your help! A situation has happened!* sounds non-native to me.

Comment: I like "unpleasantries may arise".

Comment: @TRomano But neither does 'a situation has arisen'.  The word _situation_ here just isn't going to cut it.

Comment: @Lordology: To the contrary, "a situation has arisen" is well attested. https://www.google.com/search?q=%22a%20situation%20has%20arisen%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en

Comment: @TRomano Though it is almost always followed by _which_.

Comment: @Lordology: Well, whether it is "almost always" followed by *which* or not, what does that have to do with the choice of the verb **arise** over **happen**?

Answer (score 1):

The sentence

> Unpleasant situations happen

is correct.  It contains a subject, verb and object as required therefore is complete.  The word 'happen' grammatically works in this sentence, but whether you should choose 'happen' or 'occur' is up to you.

[See complete sentence rules](https://www.dummies.com/education/language-arts/grammar/how-to-form-complete-sentences/)

Comment: I would only quibble with the word "perfectly".

Comment: @TRomano Yes, that was a bit of an exaggeration.  I'll edit that

Comment: add a citation to enhance your answer

Comment: @lbf will do.  `